# Удалить слово из строки php которое начинается с определенного символа

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такая строка:

`$str = "Текст [img]32sdf21.jpg[/img] текст";`

Как я могу удалить данный участок из строки `[img]32sdf21.jpg[/img]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например заменой по регулярному выражению preg_replace:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

```php
$str = "Текст [img]32sdf21.jpg[/img] текст";
$str = preg_replace('$\[img][^\[]+\[/img]$', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

где $ - начало и конец регулярки, [img] искать от [img] до тех пор [^[]+ пока не будет найден символ [ и [/img] строка [/img] включительно.

Так как символ [ являеться ключевым в регулярках, то его строчное представление надо исключать символом \.